# How to implement simple terminal line editing similar to input() but handling escape character

Tags: python, unix, terminal

How can I implement a Python function to run on Unix systems (minimally, just Linux) that is similar to builtin `input()`, but supports using the escape key to cancel inputting text?  So:

- Enter a single line of text at the command line (multiple lines would be OK also)
- with simple line editing (left/right arrow keys, backspace to delete a character, control-a to jump to start of line, control-e to jump to end of line, control-w to delete a word)
- (and allowing pastes from primary or clipboard selection in X/wayland -- I guess this requires no special support)
- submit the text by hitting the return key
- or hit the escape key to exit and cancel (it would be OK but not ideal if I couldn't tell the difference between this and the user entering an empty string and hitting return)

How can I achieve that?

I've tried curses, but that is focused on whole-screen input -- it seems hard to implement something that does not clear the screen.

I've tried termios, but I don't know how to implement the backspace key for example, and I suspect I might end up wanting slightly more functionality than is immediately obvious -- for example control-w, which on my linux machine `input()` implements to delete a whole word.  I don't need to reproduce every little detail of input()'s behaviour, but a few things like that (see the list above).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: Did you see the part of my question about curses?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [readline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html), for example

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import readline

input('hello: ')
```

This takes your `~/.inputrc` settings into account. You can configure `editing-mode` that controls which default set of key bindings is used. By default, Readline starts up in Emacs editing mode, where the keystrokes are most similar to Emacs. This variable can be set to either `emacs` or `vi`.

Comment: Does `editing-mode` allow me to exit editing by pressing escape, though?  That's my goal

Comment: With some configuration changes perhaps: https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC9

Comment: I scanned through that for mentions of "escape" and none seem relevant. The #SEC9 url fragment doesn't seem to link to any part of that document?